# Mathematical induction (prove divisibility)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

[image]

My attempt at the solution is to let P(n) be $10^{3n} + 13^{n+1}$

P(1)= $10^3 + 13^2 = 1169$

Thus P(1) is true.

Suppose P(k) is true for all $k \in N$ 
$\Rightarrow P(k) = 10^{3k} + 13^{k+1} = 10^{3k} + 13\cdot13^{k}$

$P(k+1) = 10^{3k+3} + 13^{k+2} \\ P(k+1) = 1000\cdot10^{3k} + 169\cdot13^k \\ P(k+1) = (10^{3k} + 13\cdot13^k) + 999\cdot10^{3k} + 12\cdot13^{k+1}$

My solution is not divisible by 7. I've always use this method to solve these types of questions. Can someone point out my error?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$P(k+1)-13P(k)=10^{3(k+1)}+13^{k+1+1}-13[10^{3k}+13^{k+1}]$$

$$=10^{3k}[1000-13]$$

Now $1000-13$ is divisible by $7$

So, $P(k+1)$ will be divisible by $7\iff P(k)$ is

Comment: So the method I used above is not applicable to this question?

Comment: @Ying, How can you say "My solution is not divisible by $7$"

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I corrected a typographical error in the expression $10^{3(k + 1)} + 13^{k + 1 + 1} - 13[10^{3k} + 13^{k + 1}]$ which I discovered while checking your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It would be convenient if we could find $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
\begin{align*}
1000 &= a + 7b \\
169 &= 13a + 7c
\end{align*}
If such integers existed, then we'd be done, since:
$$
P(k + 1) = 1000 \cdot 10^{3k} + 169 \cdot 13^k = a(\underbrace{10^{3k} + 13 \cdot 13^{k}}_{\text{divisible by $7$}}) + 7(b \cdot 10^{3k} + c \cdot 13^k)
$$
Indeed, by modding each term by $7$ in the first two equations, we find in both cases that $a = 6$, which yields $b = 142$ and $c = 13$, as desired.